# Laravel: Changing URL based on Localization

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, localization, locale

I know I have the possibility to [translate strings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization) in Laravel. But how can I also translate the URL if I switch from `en` to `fr`? For example if I'm here `example.com/morning` and I click on the french flag, I want to go to `example.com/fr/demain` or `example.com/demain` - how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Default Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#default-values) in URL generation. With a Middleware you can inject some variables, in this case, based on the locale of your app.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this, because it just helps me to define the locale automatically for the route, but the remaining parts of the URL stay the same - and this is exactly what I do not want.